# Issue passing argument in fprintf

Tags: c

> warning: passing argument 2 of ‘fprintf’ from incompatible pointer
>      type
>
> warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
>
> stdio.h:333: note: expected ‘const char * **restrict**’ but argument is of type ‘struct FILE *’

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main (void){
    FILE *file;
    unsigned char *buffer;
    unsigned long fileLen;

    //Open file
    file = fopen("squirrel-gray.jpg", "rb");
    if (!file)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s", "squirrel_gray.jpg");
            return;
    }

    //Get file length
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileLen=ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    //Allocate memory
    buffer=(char *)(fileLen);
    if (!buffer)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!");
                            fclose(file);
       }
    fclose(file);

    FILE *image;
    image = fopen("img.jpg", "w");
    fprintf(image, file);
    fclose(image);

}
```

Comment: You're just writing a file *pointer* to your output file - you need to read the *contents* of your input file and write this to your output file. See man fread and man fwrite.

Comment: You need to look into the documentation for fprintf(). This isn't a good use of it. Makes more sense to use fwrite(). Also, don't cast the file length to a pointer. Just check it directly: `if(fileLen == 0)`

Comment: The code "seems to work" but produces incorrect output.  I'd suggest that is is by definition not working.

Comment: What's not clear about the warning?

Comment: Removed the fluff text from the post, good answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line:

```
fprintf( image, file ) ;
```

`file` is a `FILE*` not a format string.  The compiler warning means exactly what it says (and is a semantic error).

Presumably you had intended to write the content of `buffer` to img.jpg? That being the case:

- you have not read any data into the buffer,
- you have not allocated any memory to buffer,
- formatted I/O is entirely inappropriate for writing binary files in any case.

Perhaps:

```
//Allocate memory
buffer = malloc( fileLen ) ;
if( buffer == NULL )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Memory error!" ) ;
}
else
{
    // Read data from file
    fread( buffer, 1, fileLen, file ) ;

    // Write data to image (img.jpg)
    FILE* image = fopen( "img.jpg", "wb" ) ;
    if( image != NULL )
    {
        fwrite( buffer, 1, fileLen, image ) ;
        fclose( image ) ;
    }
}
fclose( file ) ;
```

Comment: +1 for a clear answer.  Good to check for `buffer == NULL`, even though the need is rare.  But, IMO, result of `fread()` is far more likely to not be as expected and deserves a check - even more so than `malloc()`.

Comment: @chux : The check for malloc was in the original code, otherwise I might not have bothered; comprehensive error checking can add a lot of code obfuscating the main point of the answer - that should not be taken as license not to do it in the final code of course.  Given the sucess of opening the file and the method of determining the size, the fread seems an an unlikely failure point perhaps, but should nonetheless be checked - an exercise for the reader!